# Android linearlayout animation

Tags: android, layout, animation, background, android-linearlayout

Hi i have a linear layout which i'm using as a bottom bar in a listview and when zips are pressed i show the layout and hide it at other times. I decided it would look nicer to slide it up so i wrote the following and an animation xml which all works well. However when it slides in it shows a black background where the layout is sliding into. How can i change that background to show as transparent so the listview shows and the layout slides over the listview rather than a black background.

```
LinearLayout mainLayout=(LinearLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.bottombar);
Animation slideUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_up_in);
mainLayout.startAnimation(slideUp);
mainLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
```

Thanks for any help

**===Edit===**

Screen shots of what's happening

**This is the list view before a zip is selected**

[image]

**This is it right before the slide (white background now changed the activity theme to light)**

[image]

**And this is it mid slide (sorry about the toast)**

[image]

Comment: What is the parent view of this linear layout that you are trying to animate in?

Comment: do you want to change the background of your linearlayout on when the animation start  , or when the animation end???

Comment: The parent view of the linear layout is a relativelayout if you need to see the layout let me know. And @Houcine i want to change the background of the animation start. Like when i select a zip a black background shows then the linearlayout slides over that black background which filled the linearlayout space

Comment: so , you can set an AnimationListener on your Animation slideup , and override the method onAnimationStart () , and change the Background of your Layout with a black color :)

Comment: @Houcine well the layout has a red color and i need that set as the background when it's completely visible so i'm a little confused as to what i should do sorry

Comment: now you want to change the background of your layout to Black at Animation Start , and you want to set the background to Red at the Animation End ? it that what you want ??

Comment: @Houcine no the layout is always red i'll post a screen shot of what i'm talking about one second

Comment: @Houcine now as you can see in the screen shots a white background shows over the listview and then they layout slides over that i don't want that white background i want it to show the listview and have the layout just slide over that. Picture two shows it exactly you can see that big white space over the listview where the layout is sliding to